# Best practices: displaying text that was input via multi-line text box

Tags: html, textarea

I have a multi-line text box.  When users simply type away, the text box wraps the text, and it's saved as a single line.  It's also possible that users may enter line breaks, for example when entering a "bulleted" lists like:

```
Here are some suggestions:
 - fix this
 - remove that
 - and another thing
```

Now, the problem occurs when I try to display the value of this field.  In order to preserve the formatting, I currently wrap the presentation in `<pre>` - this works to preserve user-supplied breaks, but when there's a lot of text saved as a single line, it displays the whole text block as single line, resulting in horizontal scrolling being needed to see everything.

Is there a graceful way to handle both of these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way of dealing with this is turning all line breaks `\n` into `<br>` line breaks. In PHP for example, this is done using the `nl2br()` function.

If you want something a bit more fancy - like the list you quote getting converted into an actual HTML `<ul>` for example - you could consider a simple "language" like [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) that SO uses. It comes with natural, simple rules like

```
# Heading 1
## Heading 2
### Heading 3

* Unordered List item
* Unordered List item

1. Numbered List item 
2. Numbered List item
```

etc....

Comment: I don't think my users would understand Markdown, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php function nl2br() It transforms line breaks into 
 elements

Answer (score 1):

Convert newline characters to `<br />` tags explicitly, and let the browser word-wrap the text normally. That preserves the breaks the visitor entered, without harming other paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace line breaks with HTML line breaks.

Replace `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` (depending on the browser and platform, check first for longer one) with `<br/>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally replace all `CR/LF` with `LF`, and then replace all `LF` with `<br />`. You can then render this text inside any HTML container you want and let it flow naturally.