# Preserve Line Breaks in ASP.NET Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a multiline TextBox whose .Text property get saved in an SQL 2008 DB.  When I submit the TextBox, I loose the returns.  How do I handle this?

I've used Enviroment.Newline() to do some HTML conversion stuff, but I've never ran into this specific problem.

Edit: Nevermind, it was working just fine, but I was replacing "\n" incorrectly.  Stupid mistake.  I have to convert the "\n" to `<p>` tags.  I've done this before, but if anybody wants to answer, I'll mark their answer as correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practices: displaying text that was input via multi-line text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007024/best-practices-displaying-text-that-was-input-via-multi-line-text-box)

Comment: You can just answer your own question and mark that as correct.

Comment: For some reason I don't see an edit history here....

Answer (score 5):

You've solved your own question already, which is great.

But I would comment on one thing: You say you're replacing `\n` with `<p>` but the way it sounds like you're doing it, I'd suggest replacing with `<br>` instead.

Cheers.   -S.

Comment: @BH In XHTML, it's <br />.  In HTML, <br> or <br /> work (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5).